# excel list cells based on condition

Tags: excel

I am new in writing excel formula
Please help me in writing a formula in excel sheet (2010 onward)

Below is my excel sheet content

SN    USN          NAME         1st Test Marks     Attd(%)
1   XYZ1234        ABC              15               75

I want to **list** the students name with their USN if the test score is less than 15. This need to be achieved with serial number, USN and their names as shown below:

Name of the students who scored less than 15 are:
Sl.No      USN        Name of Student

Could any one help me with the formula or the script?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a layout as shown top left a PivotTable, constructed as shown on the right and shown middle left with a filter as shown at bottom left and that `SI.No` is also known as `SN`, should serve:

[image: SO32612405 example]